# how to find if time is between two given times using moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetime-conversion

i 3 given times, i want to check if myTime is in between start time and end time.

import moment from "moment";

```
const startTime= moment("18:45", "hh:mm").format("hh:mm a");
const endTime = moment("09:30", "hh:mm").format("hh:mm a");
const myTime= moment("19:00", "hh:mm").format("hh:mm a");

console.log(startTime, endTime , myTime);
// starttime 18:45
// endTime 09:30
console.log(moment(myTime).isBetween(startTime, endTime ))
```

Comment: You are formatting them as a string using .format(). Delete these from all three times and it should work.

Comment: @Raffael - Not quite, there's the issue that they're all on the same day.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the time isn't between the start and end times. All of your times are being treated as being on the **same day**, since you're just parsing time values without dates. `19:00` is not between `09:30` and `18:45`. It **would** be between `18:45` on one day and `09:30` the *next*, but that's not what you're testing. (Even though the documentation says the "smaller" value should be in the first argument, it still looks at the actual values, it doesn't guess that you meant one of them to be later.) If you want to test that, add a day to `endTime`. I also recommend **not** formatting prematurely; only format for output.

```js
const startTime = moment("18:45", "hh:mm");
const endTime = moment("09:30", "hh:mm");
if (endTime < startTime) {
    endTime.add(1, "day");
}
const myTime = moment("19:00", "hh:mm");

console.log(`startTime = ${startTime.format("yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm a")}`);
console.log(`endTime = ${endTime.format("yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm a")}`);
console.log(`myTime = ${myTime.format("yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm a")}`);

console.log(myTime.isBetween(startTime, endTime));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```